# VLookup result not showing

Tags: vba

I have a worksheet where i have used Instr function to cut out required text from a string. Now, i am trying to use VLookup
to find out the exeact/actual name in respect of that text using a different workbook where my database is placed.
but the VLookup resut is not coming on the required column.

Can anyone suggest what should be required course of action for this.
Entire code is mentioned below for reference purpose.

```
    Dim lastrow As Long, Text As String, DESPOSITION As String, i As Integer
lastrow = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
    Text = Cells(i, 5).Value
    DESPOSITION = InStr(Text, "DES")
    Cells(i, 6).Value = Left(Text, DESPOSITION - 2)
Next i

Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TRIM(RC[-1])"
Range("G2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G2000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("G:G").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("F1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWorkbook.Save

'Do VLookup to rename Customer name
Dim y As Workbook
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\arisarka\Desktop\DATABASE\RemitterVsCustomer.xlsx")
Dim y_sheet As Worksheet
Set y_sheet = y.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim endrow As Long
endrow = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

Set myrange = y_sheet.Range("A2:B86")
For ii = 2 To endrow
      Cells(ii, 7).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(ii, 6), myrange, 2, False)
Next ii
```

Comment: What does _not coming on the required column_ mean?

Comment: VLookup result not coming in column G

Answer (score 0):

To address the primary question, I think there is an issue with the ranges not being fully qualified, and/or incorrectly set.

When you open Workbook y it becomes the active workbook. At that point `Cells(ii,7)` refers to the active workbook (y) because it is not fully qualified, I think you are intending this to be in Workbook x though:

```
For ii = 2 To endrow
      x.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ii, 7).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ii, 6), myrange, 2, False)
Next ii
```

The next problem is going to be if the `VLOOKUP()` throws an error. You can address this by putting the vlookup in a separate function:

```
Private Function vlookup(value As Variant, rng As Range, col As Integer, mode As Boolean)
    On Error GoTo uhoh:
    vlookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup(value, rng, col, mode)
    Exit Function
uhoh:
    vlookup = ""
End Function
```

Then call the function from your loop, and if it fails you'll get an empty string rather than an error:

```
For ii = 2 To endrow
      x.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ii, 7).value = vlookup(x.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ii, 6), myrange, 2, False)
Next ii
```

I would also clean up a few other things:

First, `lastrow` and `endrow` are referring to the same range, and you haven't changed the size of this range:

```
lastrow = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
endrow = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

maybe `endrow` was intended to be in Workbook y? If not, then you can just reuse `lastrow`.

I ran into a few issues due to undeclared variables (myRange, x), maybe they are included in code that you didn't supply? I assume that x is the active workbook.

I also had to change DESPOSITION to an Integer. You have it as `String`, but you are setting it to the result of an `INSTR()` which is of type `Integer`.

After fixing those minor issues, you can clean up some of the code by taking out the unnecessary copy paste.

There are more opportunities here, but as an initial pass this would be pretty good:

```
Sub test()

    'DESPOSITION changed to integer
    Dim lastrow As Long, Text As String, DESPOSITION As Integer, i As Integer

    'I added these, you may already have them in code you didnt share:
    Dim x As Workbook
    Set x = ThisWorkbook

    lastrow = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Just put the value you want directly into Column F, deprecate all the copy/paste stuff.
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        Text = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).value
        DESPOSITION = InStr(Text, "DES")
        x.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Left(Text, DESPOSITION - 2))
    Next i

    x.Save

    'Do VLookup to rename Customer name
    Dim y As Workbook
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\arisarka\Desktop\DATABASE\RemitterVsCustomer.xlsx")

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        With x.Sheets("Sheet1")
          .Cells(i, 7).value = vlookup(.Cells(i, 6), y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
        End With
    Next i

End Sub

Private Function vlookup(value As Variant, rng As Range, col As Integer, mode As Boolean)
    On Error GoTo uhoh:
    vlookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup(value, rng, col, mode)
    Exit Function
uhoh:
    vlookup = ""
End Function
```